# Calculate $\sum\limits_{m=0}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{m}\frac{1}{m!} \binom{m}{i} a^{i}b^{m-i} $

Tags: functional-analysis, summation

Prove that $$\sum\limits_{m=0}^{\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{m}\frac{1}{m!} \binom{m}{i} a^{i}b^{m-i}. =\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=i}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i!(m-i)!}a^{i}b^{m-i} $$

I'm stacked how changed two sums

I don't know where to start. Any clues?

Comment: Draw a grid showing the pairs of $(m,i)$ values.

Comment: There is a formula to compute  ${m\choose i}$. Try using that.

Comment: Mentally: $e^{a+b}$. There are two familiar patterns.

Comment: I have a problem with sum indexed

Answer (score 0):

Think  of  $(a+b)^m $ and of $e^{a+b}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You can take $\frac{1}{m!}$ outside of your inside sum to get

$$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m!}\left[\sum_{i=0}^m \binom{m}{i} a^ib^{m-i}\right].$$

The inside bracketed sum should look familiar (where else have you seen binomial coefficients in sums?)...

Comment: @I know $\left[\sum_{i=0}^m \binom{m}{i} a^ib^{m-i}\right] =(a+b)^m$

Comment: @user62498 Great! Now substitute that in for that sum -- do you get another sum you recognize?

Answer (score 0):

The first sum is indexed by the set $\{ (m,i) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \mid i \le m \}$, and the second sum is indexed by the set $\{ (i,m) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \mid m \ge i \}$. The function $(m,i) \mapsto (i,m)$ defines a bijection between these two sets.

Moreover, the quantities $\displaystyle\dfrac{1}{m!} \binom{m}{i} a^ib^{m-i}$ and $\displaystyle\dfrac{1}{i!(m-i)!} a^ib^{m-i}$ are equal.

So in particular the sums are both equal, since they sum the same quantities over the same range of variables.

The first sum can then be evaluated using the binomial theorem and the power series definition of the exponential function.